# Does AFTER Column clause in a mysql query to add a column reduce or cause an impact on performance?

Tags: mysql

I recently presented the following query for a review

```sql
ALTER TABLE services.audit_log 
    ADD COLUMN unique_id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL 
        COMMENT 'meta data: unique id for each of the bulk operation' 
        AFTER audit_log_id;
```

And the response was I have to remove the 'AFTER audit_log_id' as it would reduce performance. need some details how it would affect performance.

Comment: In general - it cannot effect the queries performance. It can decrease ALTER TABLE performance itself (it can make ONLINE method non-applicable, and COPY will be used). The column posession specifying makes sense only when `SELECT *` is used (which is bad practice in most cases), when separate columns names are specified then the columns posession order doesn't matter.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This is mentioned too - 2nd sentence.

Comment: The response I got in a discussion WHY NOT remove the AFTER clause as follows : "The problem here is that this has to run a table upgrade across a long, complicated replication chain, and doing column ordering on ALTER TABLE often makes that upgrade much slower, which leads to unnecessary downtime for the business."